# Installing bamboo fencing

Tags: fence

Our patio is square with 8 foot sides.  For added privacy I was thinking about installing bamboo fencing on both sides and leaving the front open.

I came across bamboo material similar to this:

[Sample Bamboo Fencing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BPP2MC)

My question is how would I secure this in the ground?  I'm assuming fence posts but how big and how many?  Also, how would you secure the bamboo to the fence posts?  Is there any other secure method I could use without using concrete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you do not have a lot of weight to support but you need to keep the bamboo off the ground to prevent rotting you could try some of [the newer fence posts](http://www.hooverfence.com/catalog/hardware/oz-post/) that are metal spikes that you hammer into the ground.  Slot a four by four into the post, add a two by four stringer parallel to the ground to support the bamboo then all you have to do is wire the bamboo to the fence posts.  This is  somewhat removable and reusable if you use screws for the stringer.

Edit I made a stair rail using these posts and found the only problem is that the spike can twist or rotate as you hammer it in making it difficult to get a good fit for the stringer. Care when installing can take care of this.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!!!!